# Replacing date within a JSON config file

Tags: linux, bash, date, sed

I'm new but trying to get a new script running but I need it to call on todays date as a variable within the configuration file so the program can be run.

I'm sure sure the best way to implement it so far this line will replace the correct part of the configuration file I need but I can't figure out how to get it to use the "todays date" e.g. date +%F command.

```
sed -i 's/"to_date":.*/"to_date":"date +%F"/' /config/settings
```

config following:

```
{
 "username":"admin",
 "password":"redhat",
 "assumeyes":true,
 "to_date": "2011-10-01",
 "skip_depsolve":false,
 "skip_errata_depsolve":false,
 "security_only":false,
 "use_update_date":false,
 "no_errata_sync":false,
 "dry_run":false,
 "errata": ["RHSA-2014:0043", "RHBA-2014:0085"],
 "blacklist": {
              },
 "removelist": {
              },
 "channels":[
             {
                "rhel-x86_64-server-5": {
                    "label": "my-rhel5-x86_64-clone",
                    "existing-parent-do-not-modify": true
                },
                "rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-5": {
                    "label": "my-tools-5-x86_64-clone",
                    "name": "My Clone's Name",
                    "summary": "This is my channel's summary",
                    "description": "This is my channel's description"
                }
             },
            {
                "rhel-i386-server-5": "my-rhel5-i386-clone"
             }
           ]
}
```

Comment: For reference the value within the file is the following:
 "to_date":"2017-01-01"

Comment: Add your actual file. Is the entry present as `to_date` or `"to_date"`?

Comment: Looks like a `JSON` and _broken_, have you considered  using fixing it appropriate `JSON` parsers?

Comment: Hi Inian, Sorry i'm not great could you confirm what i need to do? If i run the command date +%F manually it does give the correct date etc just when i try to use it within the sed command. Thanks!

Comment: The file you have provided seems to be having `JSON` syntax, using `sed` or other text processors is are not the right tool for manipulate `JSON`. You need a parser like `jq`, but even then the input file is not complete. The brace `{` is not terminated. Can you provide the complete input `JSON` and are you allowed to use `jq`?

Comment: Hi Inian please find attached to the main one now, it is just a configuration file that is read the only part i need to change is the date value so it shows todays date so that the script can run and pull todays information off instead of the fixed date given, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a proper [`JSON` parser `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with the `--arg` field to pass the current date,

```
jq --arg inputDate $(date +%F) '.to_date = $inputDate' /config/settings
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "redhat",
  "assumeyes": true,
  "to_date": "2017-01-27",
  "skip_depsolve": false,
  "skip_errata_depsolve": false,
  "security_only": false,
  "use_update_date": false,
  "no_errata_sync": false,
  "dry_run": false,
  "errata": [
    "RHSA-2014:0043",
    "RHBA-2014:0085"
  ],
  "blacklist": {},
  "removelist": {},
  "channels": [
    {
      "rhel-x86_64-server-5": {
        "label": "my-rhel5-x86_64-clone",
        "existing-parent-do-not-modify": true
      },
      "rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-5": {
        "label": "my-tools-5-x86_64-clone",
        "name": "My Clone's Name",
        "summary": "This is my channel's summary",
        "description": "This is my channel's description"
      }
    },
    {
      "rhel-i386-server-5": "my-rhel5-i386-clone"
    }
  ]
}
```

The [`jq download and usage`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) instructions are pretty straight forward. Recommend using it for manipulating `JSON`, instead of depending upon `regex`.

`jq` does not edit the file in-place, save it to a temporary file and rename it back, using `GNU mktemp`

```
jsonTemp=$(mktemp)
jq --arg inputDate $(date +%F) '.to_date = $inputDate' /config/settings > "$jsonTemp"
mv "$jsonTemp" /config/settings
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that is giving the required output but doesn't save the file? am i missing something I am obviously going to read up on jq afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

To include the output of a command inside some quoted text, you have to use a subshell and use double-quotes so the text will get expanded :

```
sed -i "s/\"to_date\":.*/\"to_date\":\"$(date +%F)\"/" /config/settings
```

Also I second Inian's comment : you should be using `jq` to manipulate JSON data.

For example, the following command should do the modification you need :

```
jq ".toDate = $(date +%F)" /config/settings
```